# Setting boostrap carousel class to active when used in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to a modal that uses bootstrap's carousel. The issue I am having is with getting the right image to show when clicked. Currently it opens to either the first image in the gallery or the last image that was active when the modal was closed.

I'm wondering if anyone knows a way (with jQuery id imagine) to change .carousel-indicators and .carousel-inner's class to active when its corresponding thumbnail is clicked. I'm using bootstrap 3 and rails 4

html:

```
<div class="container">

  <ul class="row">
    <% @gallery.images.each do |image| %>
        <li>
          <a id="thumb" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox">
            <img id="imagesource" src="<%= image.photo.url(:thumb) %>">
          </a>
        </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>

  <div class="modal fade and carousel slide" id="lightbox" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="modalCarousel" class="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <% @gallery.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
                  <li data-target="#lightbox" data-slide-to="<%= index %>" class="<% 'active' if index == 0 %>"></li>
              <% end %>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <% @gallery.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
                  <div class="item <%= 'active' if index == 0 %>">
                    <img src="<%= image.photo.url(:large) %>">
                    <div class="carousel-caption"><p><%= image.caption %></p></div>
                  </div>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.carousel-inner -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#lightbox" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#lightbox" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Right now I'm using `<%= 'active' if index == 0 %>` for setting the classes to active for the first image in a gallery. However I think I need to use some javascript for getting the right photo to open in the modal when clicked. I am using jQuery so any answers/hints specific to that would be great (bearing in mind my low level of knowledge)!

Thanks so much!

**Solved**

ryantdecker's solution is great!

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Best of luck on the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the method provided on the bootstrap carousel:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-methods

Specifically, `.carousel(number)` seems to be what you are looking to do.  If the order of the thumbnails matches the order of the slides (I'm assuming it would), you should be able to do something like:

```
    $('a.thumb').each(function(index){
        $(this).click(function(){
           $('#myModal').modal('show');
           $('.carousel').carousel(index);
        });
    });
```

NOTE: Be careful of using ID attributes in loops - duplicate ID elements will cause you a lot of problems...I've used a class here (class="thumb" not id="thumb" on the anchor) instead for that reason.

Edit: Added a Codepen example - seems to be working with one extra line - needed to manually call the modal inside the function.  Line added above (`$('#myModal').modal('show');`).

http://codepen.io/ryantdecker/pen/zGNmpK

Comment: Hmmm I did not know that! Makes sense! However this is not working yet. Will keep messing around, but the same issue seems to be persisting! Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated as well!

Comment: Its telling me in the console that .carousel isnt a method. Could be relevant?

Comment: It could be that the script you are using is getting called before bootstrap and/or jQuery are loaded.  I probably should have mentioned to wrap it In a document.ready, as well, if you aren't already.  I wonder if I'm missing something about the scope (calling the method inside a function) but I don't think that should be a problem here.

Comment: Added a Codepen example to my answer - seems to work fine, just had to add the modal trigger inside the function.

Comment: can you tell me how to alter the java script to fit my carousel so that it will set the clicked image to active:
I am creating the gallery using php script problematically.
The path to my test page is:

http://www.dnd-production.com/test/autoGal.php#carIDmyGallery

Comment: at a glance it seems like you could use the above just fine, but you'd need to loop through `$('.card')` instead of `$('a.thumb')` but you also already have the data-slide-to attribute, so you really don't need the loop, you could just reference that:

`$('.card a').click(function(){
           var cardNum = $(this).attr('data-slide-to');
           $('#myModal').modal('show');
           $(this).carousel(cardNum);
        });
    });`

sorry - comments are terrible for formatting, but maybe that will get you headed in the right direction